# Проблема с Fragment'ами в ViewPager

Tags: android, android-viewpager

Задумка такая: Есть экран с  ViewPager где должно отображаться слово и его перевод, но перевод должен появится только после нажатия на mButtonCheck, после чего 
пользователь нажимает mButtonCheckOk или mButtonCheckNo (знал\не знал слово)  и экран пролистывается - снова появляется слово без перевода, пользователь снова нажимает
mButtonCheck - появляется перевод и так по кругу. Проблема в том что кнопка mButtonCheck делает слово перевода видимым  только при первом нажатии, но при последующих
нажатия это не срабатывает. Я думал  в начале что это проблема с обработчиками кнопок, попробывал обновлять их после каждого нажатия и т.д. но не помогло, пробовал 
делать без анимации, но тоже ничего, думаю проблема всетаки в ViewPager но ну могу понять в чем именно проблема.
Ниже привожу код активити  и фрагмента:

CheckActivity.java

```
public class CheckActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final int NUM_PAGES = 6;
    private static final String TAG = "CHECK ACTIVITY";

    private int mWordCounter = 1;

    private TextView mTextViewStatus;
    private Button mButtonCheck, mButtonCheckOk, mButtonCheckNo;
    private LinearLayout mDoubleButtonConteiner;

    private PagerAdapter mPagerAdapter;
    private CustomViewPagerV mPager;

    ArrayList<Word> mWordList;

    private View.OnClickListener mButtonChekListener, mButtonChekOkListener, mButtonChekNoListener;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_check);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        toolbar.setTitle("Проверка");
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        if (getSupportActionBar() != null) {
            getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        }

        mWordList = (ArrayList<Word>) MockData.getListWords();

        mPager = (CustomViewPagerV) findViewById(R.id.pager);

        mDoubleButtonConteiner = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.double_button_conteiner);

        mButtonCheck = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCheck);
        mButtonCheckOk = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnCheckOk);
        mButtonCheckNo = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnCheckNo);

        mButtonCheckOk.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        mButtonCheckNo.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        mPagerAdapter = new ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());


        mPager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);
        mPager.setPagingEnabled(false); //disable touch scroll

        //set scroll duration
        try {
            Field mScroller;
            mScroller = ViewPager.class.getDeclaredField("mScroller");
            mScroller.setAccessible(true);
            Interpolator sInterpolator = new AccelerateInterpolator();
            FixedSpeedScroller scroller = new FixedSpeedScroller(mPager.getContext(), sInterpolator);
            scroller.setmDuration(500);
            mScroller.set(mPager, scroller);
        } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        }


        initListeners();
    }

    private void initListeners() {

        mButtonChekListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                setButtonCheckAnimation();
                mButtonCheckOk.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                mButtonCheckNo.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                mButtonCheck.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                ((TextView)mPager.findViewById(R.id.translateWord)).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        };

        mButtonChekOkListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                setButtonOkAnimation();
                mPager.setCurrentItem(mPager.getCurrentItem() + 1);
                mButtonCheck.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                mButtonCheckOk.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                mButtonCheckNo.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        };

        mButtonChekNoListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                setButtonOkAnimation();
                mPager.setCurrentItem(mPager.getCurrentItem() + 1);
                mButtonCheck.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                mButtonCheckOk.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                mButtonCheckNo.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        };

        mPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
                mWordCounter = position + 1;

                if (mWordCounter == mWordList.size()) {
                    reDrawButton(true);
                } else reDrawButton(false);
            }
        });

        //set listeners on buttons
        mButtonCheck.setOnClickListener(mButtonChekListener);
        mButtonCheckOk.setOnClickListener(mButtonChekOkListener);
        mButtonCheckNo.setOnClickListener(mButtonChekNoListener);

    }

    private void setButtonCheckAnimation() {
        Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.button_check_anim);
        mPager.startAnimation(animation);
        mButtonCheck.startAnimation(animation);
        mDoubleButtonConteiner.startAnimation(animation);
    }

    private void setButtonOkAnimation() {
        Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.button_check_anim);
        mButtonCheck.startAnimation(animation);
        mDoubleButtonConteiner.startAnimation(animation);
    }



    private void reDrawButton(boolean finish) {
        if (finish) {
            mButtonCheck.clearAnimation();
            mButtonCheck.setText("ЗАВЕРШИТЬ");
            mButtonCheck.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.button_next_word_finish_rectangle));
            mButtonCheck.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                  //TODO: 2/2/2016 change listener
                }
            });
        }

    }

/**
     * ScreenSlidePagerAdapter
     */

    private class ScreenSlidePagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

        public ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Position: " + position);
            CheckActivityFragment checkActivityFragment = CheckActivityFragment.create(position, mWordList.get(position));
            return checkActivityFragment;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return NUM_PAGES;
        }

    }
    }


CheckActivityFragment.java

    public class CheckActivityFragment extends Fragment {
        private static final String TAG = "CHECK ACTIVITY FRAGMENT";

        public static final String ARG_PAGE = "page";
        public static final String ARG_WORD = "word";

        private int mPageNumber;

        Word word;
        private TextView tvStatus;

        public static CheckActivityFragment create(int pageNumber, Word word) {
            CheckActivityFragment fragment = new CheckActivityFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt(ARG_PAGE, pageNumber);
            args.putSerializable(ARG_WORD, word);
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            return fragment;
        }

        public CheckActivityFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            mPageNumber = getArguments().getInt(ARG_PAGE);
            word = (Word) getArguments().getSerializable(ARG_WORD);
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // Inflate the layout containing a title and body text.
            ViewGroup rootView = (ViewGroup) inflater
                    .inflate(R.layout.activity_check_fragment, container, false);

            ((TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.mainWord)).setText(word.getmEnglishWord());
            ((TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.translateWord)).setText(word.getmTranscriptionWord());
            ((TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.translateWord)).setVisibility(View.GONE);
            ((TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.textViewExample1)).setText(linkWord(word.getmEnglishWord(),word.getmExampleOne()));
            ((TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.textViewExample2)).setText(linkWord(word.getmEnglishWord(), word.getmExampleTwo()));


            return rootView;
        }


        /**
         * Returns the page number represented by this fragment object.
         */
        public int getPageNumber() {
            return mPageNumber;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Вы не понимаете, как работает `ViewPager`. Очень долго вам объяснять, в чем проблема, проще будет вам посмотреть плноценный урок по нему.

Comment: @metalurgus т.е. конкретно в чем проблема вы сказать не можете?

Comment: могу - в том ,что вы находите элемент по id: `((TextView)mPager.findViewById(R.id.translateWord)).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);`, а во `ViewPager` их содержится несколько, так как фрагменты после выхода за экран не уничтожаются. И поэтому, находится первый попавшийся элемент, а не тот, который вам нужен

Comment: @metalurgus я посмотрел несколько уроков только что, но так и не нашел ответа. может подскажите в каком направлении нужно копать?

Comment: Чтобы решить вашу проблему, нужно переделывать почти все. Я, как вы наверно догадались, не буду этого делать. Придется вам все же или разобраться самому, или заплатить на фрилансе тому, кто в этом разбирается.

Comment: @metalurgus могли бы Вы тезисно сформулировать что нужно менять?

Comment: metalurgus абсолютно прав: Чтобы решить вашу проблему, нужно переделывать почти все.
Чтоб быстрей её решить, нужно понять, что у Fragments свой жизненный цикл, и он больше чем у Activity так как должен ещё и взаимодействовать с ней. Самый быстрый и самый на мой взгляд не правильный способ, будет изменить метод создания элементов, который и мешает вам сохранению вашего перевода, к примеру поместить его в отдельное тело с условием "если переведен, то создаем и ставим перевод", "если не переведен, то создаем"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У Вас должны быть разные фрагменты

```
ViewPager pager;
public static List<Fragment> fragments = new ArrayList<Fragment>();
public static int FRAGMENT_CONTACTS = 0;
public static int FRAGMENT_PHONE = 0;
public static int FRAGMENT_FAVORITE = 0;

public static int FRAGMENTS = -1;

pager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pager_icon);
    pager.setOffscreenPageLimit(4);
    pager.setBackgroundColor(GetTheme.MainPagerBackground(prefs));

    fragments.clear();
    FRAGMENTS = -1;

    FRAGMENTS = FRAGMENTS +1;
    FRAGMENT_FAVORITE = FRAGMENTS;
    fragments.add(FRAGMENT_FAVORITE, new Fragment_Favorite());

    FRAGMENTS = FRAGMENTS +1;
    FRAGMENT_PHONE = FRAGMENTS;
    fragments.add(FRAGMENT_PHONE, new Fragment_Phone());

    FRAGMENTS = FRAGMENTS +1;
    FRAGMENT_CONTACTS = FRAGMENTS;
    fragments.add(FRAGMENT_CONTACTS, new Fragment_Contact());



    FRAGMENTS = FRAGMENTS +1;

    pagerAdapter = new PagerAdapterIcon(getSupportFragmentManager());
    pager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);
    pager.setCurrentItem(prefs.getInt(PrefsName.MAIN_PAGER_SELECT, 1), false);
```

Тогда вы сможете обрабатывать нажатия индивидуально в каждом фрагменте

```
public class PagerAdapterIcon extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

public PagerAdapterIcon(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int i) {

    return MainFrActivity.fragments.get(i);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {

    return MainFrActivity.FRAGMENTS;
}

@Override
public void setPrimaryItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
  super.setPrimaryItem(container, position, object);
}
```

}

Может быть не совсем правильно но это работает

Comment: т.е.  на каждое слово мне нужно создавать новый фрагмент?  и если у меня будет 100  слов, то нужно написать 100  фрагментов,  я правильно понимаю?

Comment: Если так то наверное не подходит, у вас выше было всего 6. А зачем Вам вообще pager? Ваш задумку проще оформит без него, просто создайте View1 в него поместите все что вам нужно дальше по нажатию кнопки далее или что там у вас включите анимацию и создайте новый View2 с новыми данными